# Envelope definition is not being properly set

Tags: docusignapi

I want to integrate docusign with the node js applicatiion. I am getting envelope id created in response but envelopes are falling in draft status, moreover I can not see any document in envelope created,
also the drafts are untitled..in short the envelope definition is not being properly set..I am using docusign-esign node js package

Comment: Can you provide a code sample, and the resulting API log that is generated from it?

Comment: So what are you sending over to the DocuSign in your request?  Please attach a sample payload that you are sending, without that we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

To create an envelope that will be sent (instead of `draft` status), set the `status` value to `sent`

Example:

```
let env = new docusign.EnvelopeDefinition();
....

// Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
// To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
env.status = 'sent';
```